# issues with installing newer cabal version for haskell vim now

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, vim, ubuntu-14.04, cabal

I would like to install this vim plugin: https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now

When trying to run the suggested installation script:

```
curl -o - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now/master/install.sh | bash
```

I get:

```
--- Cabal version 1.18 or later is required. Aborting.
```

I then try to install a newer version of cabal:

```
me@me:~/Downloads/cabal-install-1.22.6.0$ ./bootstrap.sh
```

The response I get:

```
Installed cabal-install-1.22.4.0
```

But when getting the version:

```
cabal --version

cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

**How do I get this plugin running? https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now**

**edit:** I've left out an important piece of information. when running:

```
cabal install cabal cabal-install
```

I get the following output

```
Installing executable(s) in /home/me/.cabal/bin
Installed cabal-install-1.22.4.0
```

Comment: You should check your path. You seem to have multiple versions installed and the wrong one is being picked up first.

Comment: @FDinoff can you elaborate please? sorry, beginner here

Comment: The PATH variable tells the shell where to look for executables. Its a colon separated list of directories and the shell looks in each directory for the executable it is trying to execute. To see what the path is currently set to you can run `echo $PATH`. The first executable found is the one that is run. If you run `which -a cabal` you should be able to see all a list of all executables named cabal in your path. One of them should be the correct version. If only one shows up you might need to add the directory contacting the updated cabal to the beginning of your path variable.

Comment: thank you. the output of echo path is: /home/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
 and the output of which -a cabal is /usr/bin/cabal...apologies i don't really understand what you're suggesting

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to update the installed version with `cabal install cabal cabal-install`? (Or update it through your package manager?)

Comment: as you can see, the package manager's latest version is 1.16 http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1434681895.png , regarding running cabal install, please see the end of my post, as i've posted an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$PATH` variable seems to be broken. In a comment you said it was

```
/home/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sb‌​in:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

This means that your shell (assumed to be bash) will look in the following directories

```
/home/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin
/.cabal/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sb‌​in
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
```

when looking for executable. If you look at the second item in your path it is `/.cabal/bin`. It should be `$HOME/.cabal/bin` (where `$HOME` is your home directory)

Most likely your `~/.bash_profile` has a line that looks something like

```
PATH="/.cabal/bin:$PATH"
```

you should add a `$HOME` to the above so that the PATH variable is set properly.

```
PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"
```

Before your shell was looking for cabal in `/.cabal/bin/cabal` however it isn't there.

---

Other information on PATH: http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html